# Reset sql developer password

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I forgot my SQL developer database password. How I can reset it?

Please help me to access my database back.

"Invalid username/password. logon failed"

Comment: SQL Developer doesn't have a password. If you've forgotten your database account password you'll need to get your DBA to reset it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about your database account, not about programming or your software tool/client.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you have forgotten the password of the user you are trying to connect to in SQL-DEVELOPER. If that is the case:

1. Simply launch SQLPLUS from command prompt as SYSDBA with Admin
   rights and alter the user for which you are creating the connection
   for.
2. Now back in SQL-DEVELOPER, right-click on the connection and go to
   properties.
3. In the password field, input the new password you created in
   SQLPLUS, test the connection to make sure there are no such errors
   and save the connection to overwrite the old connection with the new
   one.

If that's not the case please try and elaborate more on your question.